# What is the measures monad for FDHilb?

Tags: pr.probability, ct.category-theory, quantum-mechanics, monads

I am labouring under a particular assumption that, perhaps, needs to be corrected.  I believe that FDHilb, the category of Finite Dimensional Hilbert spaces and general linear maps is a category of convex spaces which is the Eilenberg Moore category for some measures monad.  Is this the case?  If so, what is that measures monad?

Perhaps my confusion is that FDHilb is not a category of convex spaces.  From physics, I know that the pure states of any quantum system form a convex subspace of a Hilbert space.

Edit:
When I say measures, I actually mean probability measures.

Comment: This category is equivalent to the category of f.d. complex vector spaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Hi,  thank you for your comment.  I am afraid that it does not help me though.  Could you explain a bit more how I can use that information?

Comment: Qiaochu is saying that as far as the chosen morphisms (general linear maps) are concerned, they do not reflect or detect anything about Hilbert space structure, and so categorically speaking that structure becomes irrelevant with that choice. For all the morphisms are concerned, you might as well be talking simply about vector spaces.

Comment: @ToddTrimble. Hi Todd, FDHilb, as described in Wikipedia has linear transformations as morphisms.  Are those different from general linear maps?     https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_finite-dimensional_Hilbert_spaces

Comment: No, they're not different. But that doesn't undermine the point being made. (Also, I imagine that what FDHilb is taken to mean might vary with author. For example, for some contexts it seems sensible to consider not all linear maps, but those whose norm doesn't exceed $1$. See this old nForum thread, comment #17 particularly about this point: https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/3158/dcpo-of-partial-monoids-and-its-dcpo-of-categories/

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to infer what you're after. 
    The category of totally convex spaces are the Eilenberg-Moore algebras for the monad induced by the forgetful functor from the category of Banach Spaces with non-expansive linear maps to Sets.  (See Pumplun and Rohrl, Banach spaces and totally convex spaces I, Comm. Alg. 12. (1984).   [This doesn't require a Hilbert space.]

You may be thinking of the famous result, due to Gleason, that for a given Hilbert space of dimension at least 3, there is a unique probability measure determined by each unit vector...

If you're interested in measures, rather than probability measures, then convex spaces are rather irrelevant because the set of all measures on whatever (measurable spaces, or Polish spaces, etc) form a K-module (See Meng's thesis, available on nLab, can be found under convex spaces).  Obviously a K-module is a convex space, but ...